# py.test runs tests twice if passed empty parameter

Tags: python, pytest

When I run [py.test](http://pytest.org/) in my project directory tests are run twice. However  `py.test--collectonly` collects only once. And so I have 413 items collected of which 31 are marked to skip (DB/file using). When I run the test without `--collectonly` I get 826 tests with 62 skipped, sometimes a few less.

Edit:
I discovered that it only happens when running from within bash script. I printed the command just before it is run (`py.test lib/python/ -l`). When I do the same from interactive shell I get correct result too.

Even closer look at the script (in the middle of this edit) revealed that empty "$@" is actually passed as an empty parameter and is equivalent to `py.test lib/python/ -l ''`, which causes incorrect behaviour and any parameter fixes it (like `--collectonly` did).

Comment: My guess is that in your `package/__init__.py` you have the modules imported.

Comment: You could try to run ``-vv`` (very verbose) and look at the test files actually executing.

Comment: POSIX shells are required to do word splitting for `"$@"`, so if you end up with an empty parameter, then this parameter was already given to the script.

Comment: What are your plugins? I had this bug too, each test case was being run twice. I'm on win32, I have uninstalled pytest-xdist, pytest-django-sqlcount, pytest-spec, pytest-smartcov and the problem disappeared. Pytest 2.7.1 on Python 2.7

Comment: I had this problem running from vim (with `vim-dispatch`) because I'd mistakenly passed the file twice, so `Dispatch pytest % -k some_pattern %`  (where `%` is the vim wildcard for the file)